# Is it possible to iterate over a list of strings and conditionally query an oracle database table based on the current value using SQL or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to query conditionally based on the current value in a list of strings using either SQL or PL/SQL? I am working with an Oracle Database if that helps?

Example of desired functionality (pseudo-code):

```
for stringVal in ('string1', 'string2', 'string3'):
  if (stringVal == 'string2'):
    select * from SCHEMA.TABLE where CONDITION;
  else:
    select * from OTHER_SCHEMA.OTHER_TABLE where CONDITION;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result number;
  3  begin
  4    for stringval in (select 'string1' col from dual union all
  5                      select 'string2'     from dual union all
  6                      select 'string3'     from dual
  7                     )
  8    loop
  9      if stringval.col = 'string2' then
 10         select max(sal)
 11           into l_result
 12           from scott.emp;
 13      else
 14         select min(deptno)
 15           into l_result
 16           from mike.dept;
 17      end if;
 18      dbms_output.put_line('Stringval.col = ' || stringval.col || '; result = ' || l_result);
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
Stringval.col = string1; result = 10
Stringval.col = string2; result = 5000
Stringval.col = string3; result = 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Note, however, that

- `IF` belongs to PL/SQL
- `SELECT` has to have its `INTO`; my example is a simple one and returns just a single value into a scalar variable. Depending on what your queries really return, you might not be able to do that but use e.g. a collection or a ref cursor instead

Comment: thank you littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version you are on you can do it using SQL Macros. Those are available since 19.6 or 19.7 .. simple example, you get the idea:

```
SQL> create or replace function what_shall_i_do(tab dbms_tf.table_t, col dbms_tf.columns_t)
  2                    return varchar2 SQL_Macro is
  3    stmt clob := 'select ';
  4    cnm clob;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1 .. col.count loop
  7      cnm := col(i);
  8      stmt := stmt || cnm || ',';
  9    end loop;
 10
 11    return rtrim(stmt, ',') || ' from tab';
 12
 13  end;
 14
 15* /

Function WHAT_SHALL_I_DO compiled

SQL> select * from what_shall_i_do(dual, columns(dummy));
  2*

   DUMMY
________
X

SQL> select * from what_shall_i_do(sh.customers, columns(cust_id)) fetch first 5 rows only;
  2*

   CUST_ID
__________
     49671
      3228
      6783
     10338
     13894

SQL>
```

Comment: nice naming convention

Answer (score 0):

If the condition doesn't depend on input data and the result set contains the same columns, then you may use simple view consisting of `union`s with constant as additional column and filter by that column. Optimizer is smart to figure it out and avoid access to the filtered out objects (see `starts` column).

> ```
> create view v_test as
> select
>   'table_1' as src, t1.*
> from t1
> where val = 3
>
> union all
>
> select 'table_2', t2.*
> from t2
> where id < 10
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ *
> from v_test
> where src = 'table_1'
> ```
>
> ```
> SRC     | ID | VAL | STR       
> :------ | -: | --: | :---------
> table_1 |  3 |   3 | KJVK9GPV5D
> table_1 |  8 |   3 | 5VQT72ICVR
> table_1 | 13 |   3 | 7YIYAMOAA7
> table_1 | 18 |   3 | NXGVIP1CFX
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'TYPICAL ALLSTATS LAST'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                  |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  bfc7qqct9vamf, child number 0                                                                                              |
> | -------------------------------------                                                                                              |
> | select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ * from v_test where src = 'table_1'                                                             |
> |                                                                                                                                    |
> | Plan hash value: 2711242194                                                                                                        |
> |                                                                                                                                    |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation            | Name   | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |        |      1 |        |       |     3 (100)|          |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |   1 |  VIEW                | V_TEST |      1 |      5 | 10185 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |   2 |   UNION-ALL          |        |      1 |        |       |            |          |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | T1     |      1 |      4 |    68 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |*  4 |    FILTER            |        |      1 |        |       |            |          |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 | |
> | |*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2     |      0 |     10 |   220 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                                                    |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                |
> |                                                                                                                                    |
> |    3 - filter("VAL"=3)                                                                                                             |
> |    4 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                    |
> |    5 - filter("ID"<10)                                                                                                             |
> |                                                                                                                                    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab0a92401d4319f66b0c54e3b818f5fc)*

If condition is dynamic and depends on input data, then I will go for modern [SQL Macro](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-elements.html#GUID-292C3A17-2A4B-4EFB-AD38-68DF6380E5F7) as posted in another answer.